# Is it possible to change the default animation of showGeneralDialog() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to customize a showGeneralDialog to show my Transform.scale animation. I'm just wondering if there is a way to change the default animation of the widget to a curved animation?

like a1 and a2 within:

```
      transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
```

For example, I would like the `Transform.scale` to have a `bounceIn` effect.

Also, could someone please explain the difference between `transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {}` and `pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {}` for the showGeneralDialog widget? And how do I properly use them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible by override transitionBuilder parameter.

#### 1. Creating New showDialog() method

Commonly, developer uses showDialog to put some dialog that overlays underlying
screen.

In this app, it is convenient to have new method so it can be simply reused 
through out our application.

**new_dialog.dart**

```dart
Future<T> showNewDialog<T>(

  return showGeneralDialog(
    ...
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    transitionBuilder: _buildNewTransition,
  );
}
```

> We only reuse showGeneralDialog() method, and customized its animation-related
>   parameters : its `transitionDuration` for Duration and its `transitionBuilder`
>   as Animating component.

#### 2. Defining new Animating component

In this demo we create simple animation by wrapping our `child` widget into
`ScaleTransition`. Then we defined its curve, rather in `curve` param only, or 
in both of `curve` and `reverseCurve`.

**new_dialog.dart**

```dart
Widget _buildNewTransition(
  BuildContext context,
  Animation<double> animation,
  Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  Widget child,
) {
  return ScaleTransition(
    scale: CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animation,
      curve: Curves.bounceIn,
      reverseCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
    ),
    child: child,
  );
}
```

#### 3. Display our new Dialog

Lastly, we can call this animated dialog anywhere in our app by using this 
code :

**main.dart**

```dart
RaisedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
  label: Text("Open Dialog"),
  onPressed: () {
    showNewDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Bounce In"),
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```

#### Repository

you may look repository here. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_new_dialog_animation#demo)

#### Demo

[image: BounceIn effect in Popup]

#### pageBuilder vs Transition builder

If we take look into DialogRoute definition in [Flutter Repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cb906179117a0d585bd79e43ac0e5568ef488ca6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart#L1495), we can conclude that

each showDialog() method will runs and passing parameters in this sequences :

1. showDialog
2. showGeneralDialog
3. _DialogRoute
4. PopupRoute
5. ModalRoute
   and so on
   ...

> Take look at buildTransitions method _DialogRoute which return FadeTransition by default.

As I tried, if we put **transitionBuilder : null**, by calling showGeneralDialog, The App will displays Dialog and **still got animated**.

```dart
  return showGeneralDialog(
    ...,
    transitionBuilder: null,
  );
```

Conversely, if we put **pageBuilder : null**, by calling showGeneralDialog, The App will displays nothing.

```dart
  return showGeneralDialog(
    ...,
    pageBuilder: null,
    transitionBuilder: _buildNewTransition,

  );
```

We may conclude that :

- pageBuilder although has some parameters of `Animation` and
  `SecondaryAnimation`, it is meant for **defining Widget** to display.
- transitionBuilder it is meant for **defining animation** to be
  processed, as Flutter displaying the Dialog